# How to install NASM in Windows (particularly Windows 7)?

Tags: file, input, installation, nasm

I followed the tutorial on the main website. It says just to copy the nasm.exe file. But when I open it, a black console window appears that says "no input file specified" and type "nasm -h" for help and then the windows disappears in a fraction of a second. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

From what I've seen, you don't write assembly code in the nasm command window, but in something like notepad, and then save the file to it and use nasm to compile it. I don't have a great deal of experience so this could be wrong. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Open a command window, navigate to the folder where you put nasm.exe and type "nasm -h".

Answer (score 1):

that's the reason why many programmers dislikes assembly language, no IDE.
You can search on the web for radasm, i think it works with nasm too.

Comment: Also visual studio can be used.  The community edition is free to download.  You can check github for agguro and look in the repos there for windows-assembly-programming.  But then you have to use masm which is also pretty in visual studio.